# Xamarin Form - iOS: Create file for user to view publically

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create file on User's device that he can view from Files App / iBooks etc?

I am trying to download file from my server (pdf, doc etc.) and write it on User's device for him to view later. The file is being properly downloaded and stored on device but when I open Files App on iPhone to see files, there is nothing there.

I am using [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) to write files:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
IFolder rootfolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
IFolder appfolder = await rootfolder.CreateFolderAsync(path,CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);                
IFile file = await appfolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);               
using (System.IO.Stream stream = await File.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
  {
     await stream.WriteAsync(content, 0, content.Length);
  }
```

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), anything stored in `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` is accessible by user. But I can't find anything.

I am developing a cross-platform App (Android, iOS) on Xamarin Forms. This code works for Android (with little modification in path)

Comment: From the documentation we know that Apple's file system is sandbox. Each app has its own sandbox to store data. You create an app to download files and store them to the app's own sandbox. They can't be read from other apps. We can read other app's sandbox files like: app groups or icloud, but it's not easy like store files to a public place iOS can't do that.